# Anyone know why this code gives wrong output in leet code and works fine in vs code

Tags: c, hash, hashmap, hashtable

so basically i am trying to solve a leet code problem called [two sum II] using hashing
but i am  getting error in this test case  **1,2,3,4,4,9,56,90** where i have to find two index those elements sum is equal to target **8**

well the answer of this test case is **4,5** because the sum of index4 and index5 in **array[1-8]** is **8**

**Here the problem** is when i compiled this below code in vs code it works perfectly fine and gives correct output **4,5**

but during leet code submission it throws wrong answer and showing output **1,3** instead of **4,5**

```
// here is my hash implemention code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Hash {
    int value;
    int index;
    struct Hash *next;
} hash;

hash *Hashes[10];

int hashify(int value) { return abs(value) % 10; }

void insert(int value, int index) {
    int key = hashify(value);
    if (Hashes[key] == NULL) {
        Hashes[key] = malloc(sizeof(hash));
        Hashes[key]->value = value;
        Hashes[key]->index = index;
        Hashes[key]->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
    hash *ptr = Hashes[key];
    while (ptr->next != NULL) ptr = ptr->next;
    ptr->next = malloc(sizeof(hash));
    ptr->next->value = value;
    ptr->next->index = index;
    ptr->next->next = NULL;
    return;
}

int search(int value) {
    int key = hashify(value);
    if (Hashes[key] == NULL) return -1;
    if (Hashes[key]->value == value)
        return Hashes[key]->index;
    else {
        hash *ptr = Hashes[key]->next;
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            if (ptr->value == value) return ptr->index;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

// here is hash_free function
void Hash_free() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (Hashes[i] == NULL)
            continue;
        else {
            if (Hashes[i]->next == NULL) {
                free(Hashes[i]);
                Hashes[i] = NULL;
            } else {
                hash *ptr;
                while (ptr != NULL) {
                    ptr = Hashes[i]->next;
                    free(Hashes[i]);
                    Hashes[i] = ptr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// here is two sum function code
int *twoSum(int *numbers, int numbersSize, int target, int *returnSize) {
    int *result;
    if (numbersSize == 2) {
        result = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
        result[0] = 1;
        result[1] = 2;
        *returnSize = 2;
        return result;
    } else {
        int val, element;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbersSize; i++) {
            val = target - numbers[i];
            element = search(val);
            if (element != -1) {
                result = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
                if (element < i) {
                    result[0] = element + 1;
                    result[1] = i + 1;
                } else {
                    result[0] = i + 1;
                    result[1] = element + 1;
                }
                *returnSize = 2;
                Hash_free();
                return result;
            }
            insert(numbers[i], i);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

// here is main code
int main() {
    int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 9, 56, 90};
    int target = 8;
    int numberSize = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int);
    int returnSize;
    int *res = twoSum(numbers, numberSize, target, &returnSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < returnSize; i++) {
        printf("%d ", res[i]);
    }
    free(res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you submit the code with `Hash_free();` commented out or was that call in there?

Comment: Unrelated: You could insert new values into existing buckets in sorted order. It may improve both insertion speed and search speed.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you copy-pasted the exact right code when submitting it? Is the assignment supposed to be done with hard-coded `numbers`? If you read the numbers, from file or from standard input, are you sure that reading is okay and working? Have you properly tested it?

Comment: I don't see `Hashes[]` initialization. Thus you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Zilog80 Since it's a global uninitialized variable, the system will zero-initialize it (i.e. set all elements to zero/null).

Comment: Here's one UB: `hash *ptr;  while (ptr != NULL)` - I assume you meant to initalize `ptr` with something before reading from it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo i have submitted exact same code above mention now expect main ... i have edited something i have placed hash _free there i didnt include hash_free function in my previous code

Comment: Build with warnings enabled. Your `Hash_free` uses uninitialized variables.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah that's is what i assume too

Comment: Talking about your `Hash_free` function, it could be simplified a bit: `for (unsigned int i = 0: i < 10; ++i) { hash *ptr = Hashes[i]; while (ptr != NULL) { hash *next = ptr->next; free(ptr); ptr = next; } }`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude uses uninitialized variable ...sry i dont get it can you tell me where

Comment: @AtulChourasiya Where I showed above: `hash *ptr;  while (ptr != NULL)` - When you read `ptr` In the `while` loop `ptr` is uninitialized. What value do you expect `ptr` to have when you do `hash *ptr;`? If you expected `NULL` the `while` loop would do nothing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah now i get it thanku brother

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks to u also brother

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My bad, i should not check code from my smartphone ^^

Comment: regarding: `hash *ptr;
                while (ptr != NULL) {`   This is an error.  your compiler should have told you about this problem.  The first loop iteration is testing the contents of `ptr`, but `ptr` has not been initialized to any known value

Comment: @user3629249 but it complied perfectly in vs code may be because we have not initilized  ptr with NULL either well, it doesnt matter now i have understand what was gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your "hash" variable is global, so it keeps preserving data of previous testcase executed. I have faced the same when using global variable.

Solution:
Just clear your hash or initialize it, in your main function( or the entry point function), so that it will ensure a fresh start for each of the test cases those are executed.